# one gson-2.3.1.jar file in an Android Studio project with multiple modules

Tags: android

Five app modules;
    Two modules(kickflip sdk and stripe sdk) are dependent on one gson-2.3.1.jar file. I have added the jar to the lib folder of Kickflip sdk. When I try to add this jar to Stripe's lib folder, Android Studio throws a Run-time error(Multidex error). How we can use one jar file to compile two sub module from android studio project?

code: compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')

Comment: Did you try to add the dependency on the projects build.gradle, in the root folder?

Comment: change your dependency to  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4' and remove jar file

Comment: @Jinu- i have tried this. Am getting Following Error:
> A problem occurred configuring project ':kickflipsdk'.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':kickflipsdk:_debugCompile'.
      > Could not find com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4.